# Randomising rows in a data frame so that the same value doesn't repeat twice in succession

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a data frame that looks like this (see attached image).

I want to achieve a very simple thing: shuffle the rows of this data frame but with a restriction that the numbers in the 'Identity' column never appear twice in a row (for example, if we had a sequence 112233, this would be an acceptable shuffle: 123123, but this would not: 12**33**21 because there are two numbers 3 appearing in a row).

My 'most successful' attempt so far is this:

```
def shuffling(x):    
    spreadsheetEmpty = pd.DataFrame(columns=['NeutralImage', 'EmotionalImage', 'Group', 'Condition', 'Emotion', 'Identity', 'Gender', 'trigger']) #Create an empty data frame - same columns as the original
    for index in range(0,len(x)-1): 
        while x['Identity'].iloc[index] == x['Identity'].iloc[index+1]: #if the identity in that row is the same as in the next one, shuffle again
            x = x.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True 
        else: #If we don't have two identities right next to each other:
            spreadsheet_final = spreadsheetEmpty.append(x) #Fill in the empty spreadsheet from the beginning with a pseudorandomized one
            return(spreadsheet_final)
```

However, with this code I don't achieve what I want because it ensures that only the first two numbers don't repeat next to each other and ignores the rest of the values in the column.

Does anyone have a suggestion how this function can be modified to inspect all the rows in the data frame for repetition?

Thank you in advance!

[Image of the data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Hv9c.png)

Comment: Do you actually need to shuffle or are you only shuffling to separate duplicates? What is the proportion of duplicates?

Comment: This spreadsheet is used for a study so the rows need to be shuffled to achieve randomisation of stimuli (images in the EmotionalImage column), it doesn't serve a purpose of only separating 'duplicates'. Also, there are technically no duplicates here (ignore the image names, I am using them only for testing) - there are three different images of the same person (that's why there are chunks of 3 numbers in the Identity column) and I just don't want an image of the same person appearing twice in a row, that's what I aim to achieve with the function. Hope I made it clear, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime, I managed to solve this issue so the successful function looks like this now:

```html
def shuffling(x):    
#Create an empty data frame
    spreadsheetEmpty = pd.DataFrame(columns=['NeutralImage', 'EmotionalImage', 'Group', 'Condition', 'Emotion', 'Identity', 'Gender', 'trigger', 'FixCrossColor1', 'FixCrossColor2','Combination'])
    xshuffle = x.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True) #Shuffle rows for the first time
    while any(xshuffle['Identity'].iloc[label] == xshuffle['Identity'].iloc[label+1] for label in range(0,len(xshuffle)-1)): #if identity value repeats twice in succession anywhere in the dataframe, shuffle again
        xshuffle = x.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
    else: #If we don't have two identities right next to each other, fill in the empty spreadsheet
        spreadsheet_final = spreadsheetEmpty.append(xshuffle) 
        print(spreadsheet_final)
```